# Rotate entire pspicture drawing

Tags: pst-optexp

I have this code for a pspicture drawing:

```
\documentclass[margin=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3,5)
\pnodes(0,3){A}(1,3){BS}(3,3){M1}(1,5){M2}(1,1){PD}
\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}
\newpsstyle{Glass}{fillcolor=cyan,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5,linestyle=none}
\newpsstyle{Beam}{linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid}
\begin{optexp}
\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS](M1)(BS)(PD)
\mirror[compname=M1,labeloffset=1,labelangle=90](BS)(M1)(BS){M\textsubscript{2}}
\mirror[compname=M2,mirrortype=piezo,labeloffset=1,labelangle=90](BS)(M2)(BS){M\textsubscript{1}}
\lens[compname=L,style=Glass](BS)(PD)
\optdetector[compname=Det,dettype=diode](BS)(PD)
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{beamwidth=0.2,fillcolor=red,opacity=0.5}
\drawwidebeam(A){BS}{M1}{BS}{L}{Det}
\drawwidebeam(A){BS}{M2}{BS}{L}{Det}
\end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

I'd like to rotate the entire drawing, including the labels so it takes less vertical space. Like this:

[image]

How can I do that?